# Find out if the connection to Wi-Fi was successful

Tags: scripting, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I need to do some script, which find out if the connection to the Wi-Fi was successful or not.

I have Wi-Fi configuration in */etc/wpa_supplicant.conf*.

I know how to add SSID and PSK to this file and connect to it.

I mean something like this:

```
variable ssid = "test"
variable psk = "psk"

try to connect to {ssid, psk}

if(connection == True) {
    add {ssid, psk} to the /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
else {
    echo("PSK is wrong, try it again.")
```

I don't know how to do **try to connect to {ssid, psk}**.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

killall wpa_supplicant 

sleep 1

wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c<(wpa_passphrase "$1" "$2") -B \
               -C /var/run/wpa_supplicant \
               -f /etc/wpa_supplicant.log
sleep 3

wpa_status=$(wpa_cli  status | grep wpa_state | cut -d"=" -f2)

if test  "$wpa_status" = "COMPLETED"
then
    echo "$wpa_status"
    wpa_passphrase "$1" "$2" >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
else
    echo " $wpa_status : Try again"
    exit 1
fi
```

Usage (as root):

```
# ./script ssid password
```

The `-f` will create a log file it can be used instead of `wpa_cli status` command to get the status of `wlan0` interface.

`wpa_passphrase` will save the correct "ssid" and "password" to `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

The `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` should contain:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

Assign an IP address to `wlan0` if you need to connect ( `dhclient` , `dhcpcd` , `ip` ...)

> [@TSJNachos117](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86726/tsjnachos117) comment: you can replace `grep` and `cut` with `awk`:

```
 wpa_cli status | awk -F = '{if($0 ~ /wpa_state/) print $2}'
```

Comment: FYI, in the `wpa_status=` line, you can replace grep and cut with awk: `wpa_cli status | awk -F = '{if($0 ~ /wpa_state/) print $2}'`. Do with that what you will. :-)

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Nice job ! Thanks!